# total duration per client

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I am trying to get total duration per client in hh:mm. 
Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 
            SUM(DATEDIFF(Minute, startdate,EndDate) / 60) 
                OVER (PARTITION BY clientId ORDER BY clientId)) 
       + '.' 
       + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), 
            SUM(DATEDIFF(Minute, startdate, EndDate)) % 60), 2) 
                (OVER(PARTITION BY clientId ORDER BY clientId))                        
FROM tableX
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the first portion of the time to string:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 
            CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(Minute, startdate,EndDate) / 60) 
                OVER (PARTITION BY clientId ORDER BY clientId)) AS VARCHAR(2))
       + '.' 
       + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), 
            SUM(DATEDIFF(Minute, startdate, EndDate)) % 60), 2) 
                (OVER(PARTITION BY clientId ORDER BY clientId))                        
FROM tableX;
```

Otherwise, you are getting:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value '.' to data type int.

That's because `int` has greater [date type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) and the engine is 
trying to convert the `.` to `int`in order to `SUM` (`+`) the values. The third argument is already string, as you are using `RIGHT` function, so there is no need to cast.

---

Could you try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SUM(DATEDIFF(Minute, startdate,EndDate)) OVER (PARTITION BY clientId ORDER BY clientId) / 60 ) 
       + '.' 
       + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), SUM(DATEDIFF(Minute, startdate, EndDate)) OVER(PARTITION BY clientId ORDER BY clientId) % 60), 2)                                         
FROM tableX
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it.

```
SELECT 
    clientId,
    CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEADD(MINUTE, SUM(DATEDIFF(Minute, startdate,EndDate)) OVER(PARTITION BY clientId), '00:00') ,108) 
FROM tableX
```

Comment: it works for individual records. I want it PARTITION BY clientId, so I will get to see the total per client. For example ClientA a has 2 duration, 00:30 and 00:20. I want the results to show as ClientA =00:50

Comment: Are your client table and this tableX different tables?

Comment: thank you. How can I get in touch with you off here? Contact me on your website is under construction

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
DECLARE @ClientDuration TABLE (clientId INT NOT NULL, StartDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @ClientDuration VALUES (1, '2017-10-13 09:21:53', '2017-10-13 10:22:53')
INSERT INTO @ClientDuration VALUES (1, '2017-10-14 09:21:53', '2017-10-14 10:22:53')
INSERT INTO @ClientDuration VALUES (1, '2017-10-15 09:21:53', '2017-10-15 10:22:53')

INSERT INTO @ClientDuration VALUES (2, '2017-10-13 08:21:53', '2017-10-13 10:22:53')
INSERT INTO @ClientDuration VALUES (2, '2017-10-14 09:21:53', '2017-10-16 10:22:53')
INSERT INTO @ClientDuration VALUES (2, '2017-10-15 10:21:53', '2017-10-15 10:22:53')

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        clientId,
        CAST((SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, startdate, enddate)) % 60) AS VARCHAR(3)) AS mins, 
        CAST((SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, startdate, enddate)) - (SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, startdate, enddate)) % 60))/60 AS VARCHAR(3)) AS hrs
    FROM @ClientDuration
    GROUP BY clientId
)

SELECT  clientId, 
    IIF(LEN(c.hrs) = 1, '0' + c.hrs, c.hrs)  + ' H :' + IIF(LEN(c.hrs) = 1, '0' + c.hrs, c.hrs) + ' M'  AS TotalDuration
```

FROM cte AS c

**Output :**

```
clientId    TotalDuration
1           03 H :03 M
2           51 H :51 M
```